# Copy certain text for further use

Tags: batch-file, redirect, cmd, copy

Is it possible to copy text from a txt file for use elsewhere using cmd. For example, from the follwing text:

"

ds_domain=6375

ds_station=64708

ds_asdomain=8780

"

I would want to copy the value after ds_station. So my stored value should now be 64708 and usuable elsewhere in the batch file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<"inputfile.txt" find "ds_station="') do set "%%a"
echo %ds_station%
```

The ´for /f´ command executes the `find` command to search the required line. If found, the line is stored in the `%%a` replaceable parameter and the code in the `do` clause is executed. In this case, as the source text is in the form `key=value`, this is used to execute a `set` command that defines a `ds_station` variable to hold the value.